Identify the movie about bank robbery and failed getaway of a bank clerk
I watched this movie probably 6-8 years ago, it is a newer movie (probably 90s, 2000s), it was in English, US movie, the plot should go like this:
The bank clerk and the robber make a deal to rob a bank. 
The deal is to share the stolen money afterwards. Since everything is arranged, the robber comes to the bank, but the clerk takes the money and gets away. 
The robber is after him, and the clerk has some problem with navigation to the place where the airplane should wait for him. He travels through the desert and actually gets lost. The operator he calls helps him to find his way, and they talk about their children. The news on TV already report about the robbery, and the bank clerk revels to the operator, that he is involved. As he reaches the airplane strip, he sees the pilot dead, and the operator says to him that she has been paid by the robber to lead him directly into trap.
I remember her saying something like "we all have children, I did it for them". 
The movie ends here. I can not remember the actors starring in the movie.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

I added some of the things I managed to remember, but I can not remember the actors.

This is Lost from 2004. From the Google sidebar:

Bank vice president Jeremy Stanton (Dean Cain) is lost in more ways than one: On his way to a rendezvous with his family in Nevada, he finds that the back roads do not match his maps. However, Jeremy has also lost direction from a moral standpoint, having just committed a robbery back in California during which he betrayed Archer (Danny Trejo), his ruthless partner. His only company for this long, dark road trip of the soul is Judy (Ashley Scott), an operator who gives him directions by phone.

When he finally reaches his getaway plane, he discovers the pilot is dead; turns out the operator worked with Archer all along and lured him into a trap. Here's a clip:



